# How to show error in Div tag in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a div tag as a placeholder in my view to render any errors received from a service call in angular js.

```
<div id="error" class="row"></div>
```

The function in controller is as below which makes a service call and then tries to update error tag in view.

```
$scope.send = function () {

$("error").text("");

var payment = {Id: 1, Amount: 100};

service.submit(payment, function (response) {

 var pmtResponse = Process(response);

 if (pmtResponse.errorMsg != null) {
      alert(pmtResponse.errorMsg);
      $("error").text(pmtResponse.errorMsg);
     }

 }

}
```

It shows an alert message when there is errorMsg but it does not do anything with updating error div tag. Is there any angular way of doing it? Or how can I make it work with jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: could you look at `ng-messages` API of angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages

Comment: Put the error message in your scope and bind it to the error page element. Add an ng-show to the scoped error message or add another scope variable indicating an error is present.

Comment: In jquery :- $("#error").text("ErrorTextHere");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rather than `$("error").text(pmtResponse.errorMsg);` (no need for jquery).

Your div:

`<div id="error" class="row" ng-show="errorMsg">{{ errorMsg }}</div>`

and your JS:

```
if (pmtResponse.errorMsg != null)
{
  alert(pmtResponse.errorMsg);
  $scope.errorMsg = pmtResponse.errorMsg;
}
```

That would be the "angular way" of doing this

Answer (score 1):

Use this because you are accessing div by id

```js
$("#error").text("");

$("#error").text(pmtResponse.errorMsg);
```